# mostrar imagenes de carpeta interna android DIRECTORY_DCIM

Tags: android, imagen, almacenamiento

intento listar el contenido de una carpeta (DIRECTORY_DCIM) (Android) en un listview listo las imagenes y su nombre pero no me permite visualizar la imagen, tambien muestro la imagen individual pero no puedo visualizarla solo veo su nombre, comparto un poco del codigo donde se listan las imagenes y se cargan en el listview donde se deberia visualizar.

```
@Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                      item.get(position);
                       Intent uno = new Intent(Imagenes.this, MuestraImagenes.class);
                       Bundle dato = new Bundle();
                       dato.putString("info",getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM) + archivos.get(position).getName());
                       dato.putString("filename", item.get(position));
                       dato.putString("ruta", getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath());
                        uno.putExtras(dato);
                        startActivity(uno);
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error:" + ex, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

```
public void recorrer(){
        f = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath());
        files = f.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            File file = files[i];
            archivos.add(files[i]);
            if (file.isDirectory())
                item.add(file.getName() + "/");
            else
                item.add(file.getName());
        }
    }
```

```
File directorio = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
        File imagen = File.createTempFile(nombreImagen, ".jpg", directorio);
        rutaImagen = imagen.getAbsolutePath();
```

encontre este error en el log :

> 2023-01-26 14:16:07.621 17403-17403/com.example.root.colectapp
> E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream:
> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.root.colectapp/files/DCIM/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.root.colectapp/files/DCIM/foto_Ubicacion3267204679170638575.jpg:
> open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: mi carpeta se ubica en android/data/DCIM  en el list view  listo y veo la imagen  y el nombre pero solo veo el nombre pero no la imagen ¿Necesito algún permiso? tengo WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: ¿Que muestra la excepción? te recomiendo usar el LogCat, en el catch además del Toast imprime el error y agrégalo a tu pregunta.          } catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error:" + ex, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("Error", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }

Comment: hola, no me muestra error solamente no carga la imagen, puedo ver la ruta de la imagen , modificar el nombre de la imagen pero no ver la imagen

Comment: ya adjunte codigo que utilizo para el listview

Comment: Si deseas desarrollar en android el uso del LogCat es indispensable, esto puede ser la diferencia entres solucionar algo en segundos o en dias.

Comment: lo agregare, y reviso, Gracias

Comment: hola, encontre este error en el log : 2023-01-26 14:16:07.621 17403-17403/com.example.root.colectapp E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.root.colectapp/files/DCIM/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.root.colectapp/files/DCIM/foto_Ubicacion3267204679170638575.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: Excelente @Sandii , de esta forma es más sencillo encontrar el problema, revisa mi respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

El problema se indica aquí:

> BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.root.colectapp/files/DCIM/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.root.colectapp/files/DCIM/foto_Ubicacion3267204679170638575.jpg:
> open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

estás tratando de escribir en esta ruta la cual no existe:

> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.root.colectapp/files/DCIM/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.root.colectapp/files/DCIM/foto_Ubicacion3267204679170638575.jpg

puedes notar que estás duplicando el path donde se encontraría el archivo, esto está sucediendo seguramente porque el parámetro "info" contiene también la ruta y además el nombre del archivo, en este parámetro solo debes enviar el nombre del archivo:

```
...
...
//dato.putString("info",getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM) + archivos.get(position).getName());
dato.putString("info", archivos.get(position).getName());
dato.putString("filename", item.get(position));
dato.putString("ruta", getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath());
...
...
```